# Regex match for 5 or more Capital letters in First 10 words, Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I am creating a regex to match a sentence if it has atleast 5 capital letters (preceded by a space as well) in the first 10 words . My regex is as follows:

```
(^(?:\w+\s(?= [A-Z]{5})){10}.*(?:\n|$))
```

My idea is :

```
^ Match start of string  
?: look for word followed by a boundary i.e a space     
?= Match if Capital letters preceded by a space  
.* - match everything till line end / end string.
```

I guess i need to restructure this one but I don't know how to. {10} was for the first 10 words but it looks wrongly placed.

Example strings:
**Match --**  `Lets Search For Water somewhere Because I am thirsty and i really am , wishing for a desert rain`

**Don't match --**   `fully lowercase or maybe One UPPERCASE but there are actually two uppercase letters that are preceded by a space.`

Answer (score 3):

Are you locked into using regex?  If not:

```
# Python 2.7
def checkCaps(text):
  words = text.split()
  caps = 0
  for word in words[:10]:
    if word[0].isupper(): caps += 1
  return caps >= 5
```

Edited to reflect the good feedback from @Kevin and @KarlKnechtel (and remove cruft)

Tried it out in the interpreter:

```
>>> checkCaps('Lets Search For Water somewhere Because I am thirsty and i really am , wishing for a desert rain')
True
>>> checkCaps('fully lowercase or maybe One UPPERCASE but there are actually two uppercase letters that are preceded by a space.')
False
```

Comment: Nice alternative. You could save a few characters by using `if word[0].isupper()` instead of `word[0].upper() == word[0]`

Comment: sorry , but I will be using regex only . I don't have a single string , rather I have an entire text and need to identify from there.

Comment: @Swordy How will you be delimiting your text into sentences?  If you expect it to be delimited by periods, for example, you can split it that way and feed the pieces into the function.

Comment: I use the flags re.S , re.M(multiline) and use it with re.findall

Comment: So, could you do something like `matches = [i for i in all_your_text.split(".") if checkCaps(i)]`?

Comment: Fair enough - but I'll leave you with the commentary that if you're able to express the things that separate your sentences as a regex, you could use `re.split` to generate a list of sentences, and then filter them with the function (like I did with my last comment).

Comment: The `min` call is unnecessary, as out-of-bounds *slices* work just fine: `>>> ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'][:10]` -> `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. The `str` call is also probably a bad idea; `explicit is better than implicit` and `errors should never pass silently` - I shouldn't *expect* this function to work on non-strings, and explicitly stringifying the input is throwing away that kind of type information that's meant to catch bugs in unit tests.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel.  I didn't know that about slices, and your point about expectation is well taken.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are really not built for this task, I agree. You can look for a certain number of *consecutive* matches, but getting several matches interspersed with other stuff is hard, especially if you need to keep count of the "other stuff".

Your task is conceptually oriented around words, so an approach that treats the string as words (by first cutting it up into words) makes much more sense, as @rchang showed. Making it a little more powerful, adding documentation and doing the counting a little more elegantly (simple approaches are fine, too, but I really dislike explicit for loops for "counting", building lists etc. these days):

```
def enough_capitalized_words(text, required, limit):
    """Determine if the first `limit` words of the `text`
    contain the `required` number of capitalized words."""
    return sum(
        word[0].isupper()
        for word in text.split()[:limit]
    ) >= required
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda count, word: count + word[0].isupper(), text.split()[:10], 0) >= 5
```